# How to use window-width to change a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I use Jquery's window-width to change a hyper link?

```
if ($(window).width() < 992) {
//go to facebook.com
}else{
//go to google.com
}
```

any idea on how to change my href using jquery ?

Comment: You want to change href or open a window ? Your comments are confusing

Comment: I dont see how this is confusing, i want to change the target website when my screen gets below 992px

Comment: //go to facebook.com or //go to google.com seems like you want to open these links in a window straight away. That conflicts with the title of your question "How to use window-width to change a href". I was talking about this confusion.

Comment: No problem. I answered correct already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($(window).width() < 992) {
  $("#anchor-tag-id").attr("href", "http://www.facebook.com")
}else{
  $("#anchor-tag-id").attr("href", "http://www.google.com")
}
```

Comment: This so far is the only answer that I believe answers the question. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use same expression in a single line, try below one

```
$("#anchor-tag-id").attr("href",$(window).width() < 992?"http://www.facebook.com":"http://www.google.com")
```